# Disabling scrolling on iPad in a home screen application

Tags: html, ipad, safari

I want to disable scrolling in an iPad HTML page, but it does not work when the page is launched from the home screen.

I have disabled scrolling in Safari running normally. However, when I run the page from the Home Screen, it scrolls vertically, with the bounce effect. I am currently using:

```
$(document).bind('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use touchstart instead of touchmove. This should fix the problem. The reason for this is, that no events are fired during the pan, so the touchmove event is fired too late.

Comment: It was in fact a different problem. The JavaScript was not running because of what seemed to be a bug with the caching of the home screen application, where it would use old versions of files that had been cached with the etag system.